# Remove whitespaces using Sed

Tags: linux, unix, sed

I have been stuck for some time now.

Below is the code that removes parentheses and the text enclosed within.

```
sed -i 's/([^)]*)//g;s/  / /g' *.txt
```

However, I am having a hard time incorporating into the code,

another condition that will remove extra white spaces in front of the parentheses.

What improvements can I make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
sed 's/\s*([^)]*)//g' *.txt
```

Comment: You should mention that's GNU only due to `\s`.